# Where should I install bootloader for UEFI systems?

Tags: grub2, xubuntu

I just recently reinstalled Xubuntu using manual partitioning.

I've created a separate EFI partition. The problem is I'm not sure if it chose the EFI partition to install the bootloader to.

What is the recommended way to install the bootloader in UEFI systems?

I've read somewhere that you should install it in the EFI partitions (e.g `/dev/sda1`), but I've seen some tutorials where they simply install it in the disk itself (e.g `/dev/sda`).

Are there any advantages on choosing one over the other?

Lastly, how do I know where the bootloader is installed?

Comment: When I use manual partitioning during installation, I set the mountpoint for the EFI partition to `/boot/efi`. That's you need to do to install grub in this partition.

Comment: I just created a partition with EFI type without specifying the `/boot/efi` mount point.
However, it seems like when i run `lsblk /dev/sda`, `/boot/efi` is the mount point for `sda1`. 
With that said, it seems like the installation does this automatically.

Comment: Be aware of bug 1396379 --Grub installs to wrong disk. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Your input for bootloader location is ignored, whether you specify it in the text box or the initial mount point.  After the installs starts, you can unmount/mount your own efi partition before the location gets used. Do add yourself to the bug's "Does this affect me?" list. If enough people do this, maybe it will get fixed.